# I have to write a business case to get a tester approved for our team. What so focus on?

Tags: testing

We have a team of 7-10 developers and work on multiple applications. I have been trying to get a tester approved for a while. I have been asked to write a business case to try get approval.

I am focusing on time that would be saved for the developers and the power of 10 cost of fixing bugs at different stages of the SDLC.

Is there anything else I should focus on to help non-technical business people see the light?

Any suggestions will help.

Comment: if you have to write a business case to get a tester, you have bigger problems!

Comment: This sound like a question better suited for programmers.stackexchange.com.

Comment: get managment to read this: http://www.stevemcconnell.com/articles/art04.htm

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with this:

- Reducing load on your development resource
- Better cross browser support
- Improved code quality
- Using a professional test plan, will reduce customer issues

Probably more too. At 10 devs, you should have a tester.